# VSCode and Stencil (tsx): `debugger` statement doesn't put browser into debug mode

Tags: javascript, debugging, vscode-debugger, stenciljs, tsx

I'm very new to debugging JavaScript, let alone Typescript, let alone a Stencil project that uses `tsx` files (which I assume are a certain type of reactive Typescript files).

I hoped that by adding a `debugger` statement into the code, using a refresh in Chrome the Debugging tools would show up. But nothing happens. If I add a `console.log` at the same place, it behaves as expected. But nothing happens with a `debugger` statement.

What to do? I don't want to debug with tons of `console.log` everywhere.

I'm using VSCode by the way. Don't know whether that is relevant. I read in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug that JavaScript debugging should be built into VSCode. I don't care whether I debug inside VSCode or inside Chrome - as long as I am able to debug somehow.

Here is the repository, if somebody wants to give it a try or checkout configuration files: https://github.com/NothingAG/adg-components

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the build tool (nx) runs a production build which is why `debugger` statements are automatically filtered out.

To fix it you can [explicitly instruct Stencil to run a development build](https://stenciljs.com/docs/cli):

```
npm start -- --dev
```

Comment: You are a life saver! It works, thank you!  I added it to my existing `script` in `package.json`, like so: `"start": "nx serve adg-components --dev"`, so I can run `$ npm run start` as usual. Can you tell me what the `--` in your command means?

Comment: TBH I'm not completely sure but here's an explanation: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean

Comment: Thanks, @thomas. I think we don't need the double dash in your answer then? Ie. in my project I have configured it like so, and it works without double dash: `nx serve adg-components --dev --port 3333`.

Comment: I think it's different between Windows and Mac/Linux. On Windows you generally don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding `debugger` statements in code you can always add breakpoints in Chrome Developer Tools.

1. Load your app in the browser
2. Open Developer Tools in Chrome (for example right-click on a page and choose "Inspect")
3. In Developer Tools choose tab "Sources"
4. Open the file you want to debug by hitting command-P. An input field appears where you can enter the name of the file you want to debug
5. Add a breakpoint by clicking on the line number in the gutter

Next time your app hits the breakpoint the debugger shows up.

Comment: Thanks for adding this hint. I could only see a minified `.js` file with a single line of code, so I wasn't able to set a breakpoint. Thomas' comment though gave me the answer I needed.

Comment: yeah... to be exact, I didn't answer the question :=) It's a good decision  to mark Thomas' answer as the solution.

Comment: I find `debugger` to be a good starting point to find the correct location, then I switch to breakpoints. And if you follow my answer the output is no longer minified (or at least not nearly as much).

Comment: @thomas could you explain a bit more in detail what you mean with "find the correct location" and "switch to breakpoints"? Can you switch back into VSCode somehow and use breakpoints there? Or do you set breakpoints in the browser's debugging env?